# reactjs - Element vanishing and again appearing when when inspecting that element in chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, web-frontend

In the header section, of the website I am creating, I added an image....just before the text 'Sahyog.'
Now when I saved and compiled the react app, I no longer see the image before the Text.

[image]

The number of times I reload the page....no help !!

Then I pressed ctrl + shift + i, for inspecting element in Google Chrome

[image]

The image re-appeared out of nowhere!! Don't know whats going on.

The code snippets are as follows:

The App.js code
[image]

The App.css code
[image]

Can anyone point out what's the issue here ? It's really driving me crazy.

Comment: do you have media queries for your page or component?

Comment: I don't think so. How to do that ?

Comment: I believe @Jai meant to css media query - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp. Just to be sure, resize your window to the same size when the devtools is open and see if the image is appearing.